# Logistic regression confusion matrix problem

Tags: r, logistic-regression, confusion-matrix

I tried computing [confusion-matrix](/questions/tagged/confusion-matrix) for my [glm](/questions/tagged/glm) model but I keep getting:

> Error: `data` and `reference` should be factors with the same levels.

Below is my model:

```
model3 <- glm(winner ~ srs.1 + srs.2, data = train_set, family = binomial)
confusionMatrix(table(predict(model3, newdata=test_set, type="response")) >= 0.5,
                      train_set$winner == 1)
```

`winner` variable contains `team1` and `team2`.
`srs.1` and `srs.2` are numerical values.

What is my problem here?

Comment: Check that just the `predict()` function is working as expected.  If not, you need to ensure that the factor levels in `test_set` for `srs.1` and `srs.2` are the same (or are a subset of) the factor levels in `train_set` for the same variables.  As an example, if your testing data has variable `gender` with factor levels "male" and "female", you can't have a factor level of "other" in the testing data.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose your `winner` label is a binary of 0,1. So let's use the example below:

```
library(caret)
set.seed(111)
data = data.frame(
srs.1 = rnorm(200),
srs.2 = rnorm(200)
)

data$winner = ifelse(data$srs.1*data$srs.2 > 0,1,0)

idx = sample(nrow(data),150)
train_set = data[idx,]
test_set = data[-idx,]

model3 <- glm(winner ~ srs.1 + srs.2, data = train_set, family = binomial)
```

Like you did, we try to predict, if > 0.5, it will be 1 else 0. You got the table() about right. Note you need to do it both for test_set, or train_set:

```
pred = as.numeric(predict(model3, newdata=test_set, type="response")>0.5)
ref = test_set$winner

confusionMatrix(table(pred,ref))

Confusion Matrix and Statistics

    ref
pred  0  1
   0 12  5
   1 19 14

               Accuracy : 0.52            
                 95% CI : (0.3742, 0.6634)
    No Information Rate : 0.62            
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 0.943973        

                  Kappa : 0.1085
```